# How use regexp replace in cycle for change text

Tags: javascript

I have some array with regexp to replace in text.

Now I do

```
module.exports = (text) => {
    return text.replace( /smth/g, 'smth' )
        .replace( /smth/g, 'smth' );
};
```

But how I can iterates through the array

```
module.exports = (text) => {
    const exp = [
        ['smth', 'smth'],
        ['smth', 'smth'],
        ['smth', 'smth']
    ];

    return text.toLowerCase()
        .replace(translate[0][0], translate[0][1])
        .replace(translate[1][0], translate[1][1])
        .replace(translate[2][0], translate[2][1]);
}
```

Can I use forEach or map cycle?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `for ... of` loop on your expressions :

```
module.exports = (text) => {
    const exp = [
        ['smth', 'smth'],
        ['smth', 'smth'],
        ['smth', 'smth']
    ];

    let result = text.toLowerCase();
    for(let expression of exp) result = result.replace(expression[0], expression[1]);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array, and apply the `replace` in each iteration:

```
return exp.reduce((text, [from, to]) => text.replace(from, to), exp.toLowerCase())
```

Working demo:

```js
const text = 'the quick brown fox';

const exp = [
  ['the', 'wow'],
  ['brown', 'red'],
  ['fox', 'apple']
];

console.log(
  exp.reduce((text, [from, to]) => text.replace(from, to),
    text.toLowerCase())
);
```